# Split the date and time from string in codesys v 3

Tags: stl, codesys

i 'm working on codesys . I have a string which has the DATE AND TIME .I want to split the date and time . 
    currentTime: DATE_AND_TIME; 
         showing value like this
        DT#2019-08-06-10:06:53
after concat Convert the currentTime variable into string .

Now i want to split the date and time values

```
 time :     10:06:53
  Date      2019-08-06
```

Please provide the deceleration and implementation part

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried so far, and why doesn't it produce the output you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaration part:

```
 dtDateAndTime     : DATE_AND_TIME;
 sDateAndTime      : STRING;
 sDate             : STRING;
 sTime             : STRING;
```

Implementation part:

```
sDateAndTime := DT_TO_STRING(dtDateAndTime);
sDate := MID(sDateAndTime, 10 , 4);
sTime := RIGHT(sDateAndTime, 8);
```